# infinite Loop a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, loops

Hi i have this javascript function which fades in a div if a user hovers over another div. And when they hover off or more the mouse away the div fades back out.

Does anyone know how i can loop this to run an infinite number of times because at the moment it only does it the once.

```
<script>
$(".change-profile-pic").hide();
$('.img-with-border').hover(function () {
    if ($('.change-profile-pic').is(":hidden")) {
         $('.change-profile-pic').fadeTo(0, 500);
    } else {    
        $('.change-profile-pic').fadeTo(500, 0);              
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want it to fade in and fade out infinitely once the user mouses-over the image, or when they mouse-out of the image? Or do you mean it only runs the once, when you want it to run *every* time they mouse-over/mouse-out the image?

Comment: the second thing you said. i want it to run again and again each time a user moves their mouse over it and away from it.

Comment: @KevinReeves Consider CSS animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use jQuery (not CSS transitions) then with [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [`.fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`.fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and my understanding of

> i want it to run again and again each time a user moves their mouse over it and away from it

```
$(".change-profile-pic").hide();
$('.img-with-border').hover(
    function over() { // fade in on mouseover
        $('.change-profile-pic').fadeIn(500);
    },
    function out() { // fade out on mouseout
        $('.change-profile-pic').fadeOut(500);
    }
);
```

---

Edit for no fade out when hovering over `.change-profile-pic`

```
(function setUpHover() {
    $(".change-profile-pic").hide();
    var timeout = null,
        over = function over() {
            window.clearTimeout(timeout);
            $('.change-profile-pic').fadeIn(500);
        },
        outAfterDelay = function outAfterDelay() {
            $('.change-profile-pic').fadeOut(500);
        },
        out = function out() {
            timeout = window.setTimeout(outAfterDelay, 1000); // give enough time to move to elm here
        };
        
    $('.img-with-border').hover(over, out);
    $('.change-profile-pic').hover(over, out);
}());
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpkmN/) (based on [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00)'s [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/k54gh/) with JavaScript from this answer instead)

Comment: For pulsing behaviour, see jfriend00's answer.

Comment: thanks thats spot on. the only problem i have now is the 'change-profile=pic' div fades out when you hover the mouse over it because it's obviously left the 'img-with-border' div. but i want the 'change-profile-pic' div to behave like a button, fade in in and out when not in use but stay there when hovering or clicking on it?

Comment: For that kind of behaviour, you'd have to delay the fade out using `window.setTimeout` with a reasonable amount of time. Clear the timeout when mouseover-ing so that `.fadeOut` never gets called when mouse is over it, and apply the same `.hover` functions to `.change-profile-pic`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use setTimeout() or setIntervall()
More here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: ok thanks but i'm new to javascript, is their an example you could give me, like how would i structure an interval within the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for the item to pulse in/out as long a the mouse is hovered, you can use code like this:

```
<script>
$(".change-profile-pic").css("opacity", 0);
$('.img-with-border').hover(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.data("hovered", true);

    function fadeInOut(obj) {
        if (self.data("hovered")) {
            obj.stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1, function() {
                obj.fadeTo(500, 0, function() {fadeInOut(obj)});
            });
        }
    }
    $(".change-profile-pic").each(function() { fadeInOut($(this))});
}, function() {
    $(this).data("hovered", false);
});
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/k54gh/

Conceptually, this keeps a flag on the hovered item with `.data()` for whether the item is currently hovered or not and it repeats a fadeTo 1 opacity, then fadeTo 0 opacity over and over again as long as the item stays hovered.  It uses the animation completion function of the first fade to know when to start the second one and the animation completion of the second to start the cycle over again.

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd move everything into a single function scope so I could capture the hovered state as a variable that isn't GC'd rather than setting `.data`. This method works too though.

Comment: @PaulS. - I thought this way is safer since there could be more than one `.img-with-border` item.